# I need a key binding of: "M-x compile" then in Compile commant type the "Compile command: love2d /home/huseyin/Documents/Programming/Lua/"

Tags: key-bindings, init-file, hooks

I need a key binding of: `M-x compile` then in compile command type like `Compile command: love2d /home/huseyin/Documents/Programming/Lua/`
I am tired of doing that again and again.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just add something like this to your init file:

```
(defun oleg/compile-lua ()
  "use love2d to compile my lua code"
  (interactive)
  (compile "love2d /home/huseyin/Documents/Programming/Lua/"))
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") #'oleg/compile-lua)
```

You can name the function whatever you prefer, and bind it to whichever key you like.

Comment: thanks alot, it works great.

Comment: i want to do the same thing for Lua but in Lua you must write the name of the file, as a file i want the use the name of the current file . Is it possibble?

Comment: @olegharput Usually the variable `buffer-file-name` gives what you want. So easily you can just do string concat with that.